# Ruby || and && operators return wrong results without guard

Tags: ruby

I want to create Pundit policy class but operators `||` and `&&` won't work as expected (Ruby 2.4.5). I've got below policy:

```
  def show?
    phone_present? && login.physician? \
      || login.administrator? \
      || login.delegate? \
      || (record.id == login.user.id) \
      || (!login.user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? \
           && login.user.has_patient?(record) \
           && login.user.approved_caregiver?)
  end

  def phone_present?
    record.user_demographic.phone.present?
  end
```

My idea is to check if phone number exists for current user - if not it should return `false` and then the rest logic. It turned out when the second part of `&&` :

```
login.physician? \
      || login.administrator? \
      || login.delegate? \)
```

return `true` whole expression becomes `true` even when `phone_present?` is `false. The behavior is incomprehensible because:

```
2.4.5 :092 > a = false && true
 => false
```

Even weirder is that if I put guard in there everything will work as it should:

```
  def show?
    return false unless phone_present?

    login.physician? \
      || login.administrator? \
      || login.delegate? \
      || (record.id == login.user.id) \
      || (!login.user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? \
           && login.user.has_patient?(record) \
           && login.user.approved_caregiver?)
  end
```

Why does the last example work and the first one does not? I don't wanna have guard inside `show?` method because it doesn't seem consistent to me.

Comment: So, I guess you would also say that the result of `2 + 3 * 4` should be `20` instead of `24`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that order in which Ruby evaluated the code is not how you expect it to do.

A simplified example would be

```
a && b || c
```

You seem to think that if `a == true` then `false` should be returned. That means you think it evaluates the code like this

```
a && (b || c)
```

But this is not the case. Because of Ruby's [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) the code is evaluated like this:

```
(a && b) || c
```

That means to fix the issue you need to tell Ruby that you want it to evaluate the code slightly different than the default by adding some parentheses.

```
def show?
  phone_present? && (
    login.physician? \
    || login.administrator? \
    || login.delegate? \
    || (record.id == login.user.id) \
    || (
      !login.user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? \
      && login.user.has_patient?(record) \
      && login.user.approved_caregiver?
    )
  )
end
```

Btw most of the conditions depend on `login` and `record`. I think your code would improve when you mode those conditions into a method on `login`. For example like this:

```
def has_access_to?(record)
  physician? || administrator? || delegate? \\
    || (record.id == user.id) \
    || (
      !user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? \
      && user.has_patient?(record) \
      && user.approved_caregiver?
    )
end
```

Which you could then use like this in the Pundit policy:

```
def show?
  phone_present? && login.has_access_to?(record)
end
```

Comment: By the way, this is not just Ruby's operator precedence – pretty much *every* programming language which even has a concept of operator precedence (which is practically all of them) has the same precedence as Ruby, simply because mathematics and logic also have the same precedence (and had for decades before programming languages were even invented). In fact, `&&` is just multiplication in GF(2), i.e. the field of integers modulo 2, so just like multiplication, it binds tighter.

Comment: If I use this `has_access_to?` method as a private method inside the pundit class I'll get an error: `undefined method has_access_to? for #<Login:0x00007f81daca0450>`. I know it should be defined inside the `Login` model but if I have really, really fat model I don't see the point to extract this logic to another model method.

Comment: Of course, there is no hard rule or need to extract the code into the Login class. And that is up to you. But - as I wrote in my answer -  I would extract it because that logic only depends on a login and a record, therefore it feels wrong to me that it is implemented on another object.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's operators have a certain precedence order and thus bind depending on this order (similar to how in math formulas - and ruby - multiplication bind stringer than addition.

Important for your case her eis  that the `&&` operator binds stronger than the `||` operator. Your rule thus uses following implicit precedences (expressed by adding parentheses):

```
(phone_present? && login.physician?) \
  || (login.administrator?) \
  || (login.delegate?) \
  || (record.id == login.user.id) \
  || (!login.user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? \
       && login.user.has_patient?(record) \
       && login.user.approved_caregiver?)
```

The first option is thus only `true` if there is a phonenumber and the user is a physician. The phonenumber requirement is ignored for any of the other options.

You can resolve this either with a guard  or by appropriate parentheses.

Stylewise, I personally prefer to use smaller conditions and several guards. This makes the individual rules clearer and simpler to reason about:

```
def show?
  return false unless phone_present?

  return true if login.physician?
  return true if login.administrator?
  return true if login.delegate?
  return true if record.id == login.user.id

  return true if !login.user.registry_card&.admin_actioned? && login.user.has_patient?(record) && login.user.approved_caregiver?)
  
  false
end
```

If appropriate, you may also some of the rules (such as the last one) to an additional appropriately named method. As explained above, this makes reasoning about those rules much easier and also simplifies testing.